# Switch user "su" switches to bash

Tags: linux

I am using "su - Oracle" , getting switched to "-bash-3.00$"

I am switching my user from root to Oracle, but it switches to bash-3.00$ . Now its happening with every user i have created.

Answer (score -1):

Briefly,

This is modifiable -

```
 sudo usermod -s /bin/ksh oracle
```

When creating users, you can specify the shell.

```
 sudo useradd -s /bin/ksh oracle # etc
```

*Probably* better asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Obviously never required, but would love feedback on the downvote so I can learn something, lol